# Why is the performance issue between these two queries?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, union-all, not-exists

I use below query to find specific data which has performance issue:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable AS
SELECT  /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ * FROM 
 MAIN_TABLE MAIN
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
SELECT  1 
FROM
FILTER_TABLE FLT 
WHERE 1=1 
AND FLT.CUSTOMERID = LPAD(MAIN.CUSTOMERID,10,'0')  
UNION ALL
SELECT  1 
FROM
FILTER_TABLE FLT 
WHERE 1=1 
AND FLT.COMPANYID = MAIN.COMPANYID 
);
```

AND this is the explain :

```
 Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 37.020.734.296  Bytes: 2.034.333.315  Cardinality: 500.451                      
    10 FILTER               
        4 PX COORDINATOR            
            3 PX SEND QC (RANDOM) PARALLEL_TO_SERIAL SYS.:TQ10000 :Q1000Cost: 79  Bytes: 2.034.463.395  Cardinality: 500.483        
                2 PX BLOCK ITERATOR PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_CHILD :Q1000Cost: 79  Bytes: 2.034.463.395  Cardinality: 500.483     
                    1 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL TABLE PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT MAIN_TABLE :Q1000Cost: 79  Bytes: 2.034.463.395  Cardinality: 500.483  
        9 UNION-ALL             
            6 PARTITION LIST ALL  Cost: 37.160  Bytes: 88  Cardinality: 4  Partition #: 7  Partitions accessed #1 - #2      
                5 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL TABLE FILTER_TABLE Cost: 37.160  Bytes: 88  Cardinality: 4  Partition #: 7  Partitions accessed #1 - #2 
            8 PARTITION LIST ALL  Cost: 37.111  Bytes: 56  Cardinality: 2  Partition #: 9  Partitions accessed #1 - #2      
                7 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL TABLE FILTER_TABLE Cost: 37.111  Bytes: 56  Cardinality: 2  Partition #: 9  Partitions accessed #1 - #2
```

When I edit my code to this it has not performance issue:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable AS
SELECT  /*+ PARALLEL(16) */ * FROM 
 MAIN_TABLE MAIN
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
SELECT  1 
FROM
FILTER_TABLE FLT 
WHERE 1=1 
AND FLT.CUSTOMERID = LPAD(MAIN.CUSTOMERID,10,'0')  
)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT  1 
FROM
FILTER_TABLE FLT 
WHERE 1=1 
AND FLT.COMPANYID = MAIN.COMPANYID 
);
```

AND this is explain plan:

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 74.619  Bytes: 2.059.487.545  Cardinality: 500.483                                          
    18 PX COORDINATOR                                   
        17 PX SEND QC (RANDOM) PARALLEL_TO_SERIAL SYS.:TQ10004 :Q1004Cost: 74.619  Bytes: 2.059.487.545  Cardinality: 500.483                               
            16 HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI BUFFERED PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT :Q1004Cost: 74.619  Bytes: 2.059.487.545  Cardinality: 500.483                           
                4 PX RECEIVE PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT :Q1004Cost: 37.266  Bytes: 336.233.040  Cardinality: 15.283.320                          
                    3 PX SEND HASH PARALLEL_TO_PARALLEL SYS.:TQ10002 :Q1002Cost: 37.266  Bytes: 336.233.040  Cardinality: 15.283.320                    
                        2 PX BLOCK ITERATOR PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_CHILD :Q1002Cost: 37.266  Bytes: 336.233.040  Cardinality: 15.283.320  Partition #: 6  Partitions accessed #1 - #2               
                            1 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL TABLE PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT FILTER_TABLE :Q1002Cost: 37.266  Bytes: 336.233.040  Cardinality: 15.283.320  Partition #: 6  Partitions accessed #1 - #2           
                15 PX RECEIVE PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT :Q1004Cost: 37.349  Bytes: 2.048.476.919  Cardinality: 500.483                          
                    14 PX SEND HASH PARALLEL_TO_PARALLEL SYS.:TQ10003 :Q1003Cost: 37.349  Bytes: 2.048.476.919  Cardinality: 500.483                    
                        13 HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI BUFFERED PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT :Q1003Cost: 37.349  Bytes: 2.048.476.919  Cardinality: 500.483               
                            8 PX RECEIVE PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT :Q1003Cost: 37.266  Bytes: 427.932.960  Cardinality: 15.283.320              
                                7 PX SEND HASH PARALLEL_TO_PARALLEL SYS.:TQ10000 :Q1000Cost: 37.266  Bytes: 427.932.960  Cardinality: 15.283.320        
                                    6 PX BLOCK ITERATOR PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_CHILD :Q1000Cost: 37.266  Bytes: 427.932.960  Cardinality: 15.283.320  Partition #: 13  Partitions accessed #1 - #2  
                                        5 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL TABLE PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT FILTER_TABLE :Q1000Cost: 37.266  Bytes: 427.932.960  Cardinality: 15.283.320  Partition #: 13  Partitions accessed #1 - #2
                            12 PX RECEIVE PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT :Q1003Cost: 78  Bytes: 2.034.463.395  Cardinality: 500.483              
                                11 PX SEND HASH PARALLEL_TO_PARALLEL SYS.:TQ10001 :Q1001Cost: 78  Bytes: 2.034.463.395  Cardinality: 500.483        
                                    10 PX BLOCK ITERATOR PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_CHILD :Q1001Cost: 78  Bytes: 2.034.463.395  Cardinality: 500.483    
                                        9 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL TABLE PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT MAIN_TABLE :Q1001Cost: 78  Bytes: 2.034.463.395  Cardinality: 500.483
```

So why is the performance issue between these two queries?
And Can I use a **hint** to solve this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: When you run the queries I would expect an `ORA-00904: "MST"."COMPANYID": invalid identifier` Or is `MST.COMPANYID` a function?

Comment: My first approach would be `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FILTER_TABLE FLT WHERE FLT.CUSTOMERID = LPAD(MAIN.CUSTOMERID,10,'0') OR MST.COMPANYID = MAIN.COMPANYID);`

Comment: MST ->MUST BE FLT , I edit my question. And or is the another issue. It is too slow.